# Generate pdf from markdown with appropriate formatting

Tags: pdf, file-format

How to export `README.md` file from `bitbucket.org` to `.pdf` file **with the same formatting** as they use on the `bitbucket.org` website? I tried a few convertors of `.md` to `.pdf` but output was horrible formatted or links doesn`t work. 
I tried :

1. `gimli` -poor formatting
2. `pandoc` - poor formatting
3. http://dillinger.io/ - well formatted but links in .pdf doesn`t work)

But the best way will be, if the `.pdf` looks exactly like on `bitbucket.org`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Mint I just use an application's **Print** function, choose **Print to File** and **PDF** output. Works pretty good for Firefox, Chromium, Gedit, I think anything that will do a "Print" command

Comment: It`s a good idea, but links will not work using your solution.

Comment: Links appeared to work for a webpage printed to pdf in Chromium, but I'll bet each program is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

**Foxit Reader** (disclosure: I work for Foxit) includes a PDF printer, and links should still work. If you have Windows 10, the built-in **Microsoft Print to PDF** driver should also work.